# "X style," vs "X-style."

Tags: word-usage, syntactic-analysis

Example:

> He rose from the dead **Jesus style**.
>
> He rose from the dead **Jesus-style**.

Similarly:

> This was my first time digging goat excrement. Not an item in my
>   **list of things to do before I die**.
>
> This was my first time digging goat excrement. Not an item in my
>   **list-of-things to-do-before-I-die**.

What form is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say "Jesus-style", because when you link the two words with a hyphen, they're then acting as an adverb modifying "he rose". "Dead Jesus style" is *potentially* ambiguous  -  it could mean "He rose in dead-Jesus style" [in the style of dead Jesus]  -  which is nonsense semantically but possible grammatically.  As for "list of things ...", the hyphens are unnecessary - it makes perfect sense without them. *However*, the hyphens might be recommended if the "things..." were to move *before* the "list".  E.g. "Digging goat excrement is not in my things-to-do-before-I-die list, but water-skiing is on my before-I-turn-70 list."